# Transfer data in facebook app with app_data

Tags: facebook

I have used App_data many times for transfering variable between a link and a FB application.

For exemple, the link :
http://www.facebook.com/MyPage/app_123456?app_data=hello
will show the text "hello" in the facebook app.

I have used this many times, with no problems. But now, the variable is transfered only when i'm connected with my developer account of this app. If i connect with another FB account, the variable is not transfered...

My code in the FB app :

```
<?php
session_start ();

require_once("fb/facebook.php");
$app_id = "129712360563229";
$app_secret = "5a5689a022eedf5110e235d90d51930b";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => false
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];


// THE MAGIC SAUCE
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];

// HERE IS A STRING OF YOUR APP DATA.
$app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];

echo $app_data;
?>
```

You you have an idea ?
THANKS !

Comment: Important think i just noticed :it work in http, for all account, and it doesn't in https for all account excepting my developer account. Why https make the app data not transfering ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your app is not in the 'Sandbox mode', which is when it is visible only to admins, developers and testers.

Comment: Thanks, but i have already cheking. My app is not in sandbox. Any another account has access to the app, but the app_data is not transfered. If i'm with my developper account, everything is ok... Strange